# Terminal issue, MicroPythonREPL

Tags: terminal, pycharm, esp32, micropython, esptool

I'm using PyCharm to do some kinds of stuff on ESP32,
It's ongoing, but I can't use the terminal correctly. MicroPython REPL doesn't seem to work. I can't do serial commands on the terminal.

I'm using a venv to do it, and maybe the problem is something related to it.

In normal cases, this is the terminal:
Device path COM[x]
Quit: Ctrl+] | stop program: Ctrl+C | Reset: Ctrl+D

> > > 

...

In my case, it's like this:
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.18363.1016]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\networktest>
...

So I can't do any command in my terminal, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a Terminal program like PuTTY, using the com port identified for the ESP32 to establish a REPL?

Can you see the board/com port in Device Manager or as a drive in  Windows Explorer?

These steps might help isolate the problem to either Pycharm, or the board itself?

Comment: I discovered it was PyCharm 2020.2 the problem... so just did the downgrade and everything its working.